# replace string with undefined within an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```
const test = [
{col1: "na", col2: "string", col3: "na"},
{col1: 100, col2: "String", col3: "2019-01-01"},
{col1: 203, col2: "na", col3: "2019-01-01"}
]
```

And I want to use vanilla JS to create a function naOmit that will replace the "na" strings with undefined:

```
console.log(naOmit(test))

[
{col1: undefined, col2: "string", col3: undefined},
{col1: 100, col2: "String", col3: "2019-01-01"},
{col1: 203, col2: undefined, col3: "2019-01-01"}
]
```

**Already Tried:** I've tried playing with a function that works for nested arrays, but I'm not sure how to apply this to an array of objects (or if this is even the right route)

```
rows = [
["na", "string", "na"], 
[100, "String", "2019-01-01"],
[203, "na", "2019-01-01"]
]

rows.map(function(x){ return x.map(function(y){ y === "na"? undefined: y})})
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: do you want a new array/objects? or just a mutation?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn -- the array of arrays was my attempt at addressing the "what I've tried" part of the SO asking a question formula

Comment: @Nina I think I'd like a new array of objects (but I must admit I'm fuzzy on your distinction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the objects and replace if wanted string is found.

```js
function replace(object, search, replace) {
    function iter(object) {
        Object.keys(object).forEach(k => {
            if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') return iter(object[k]);
            if (object[k] === search) object[k] = replace;
        });
    }
    
    iter(object);
}

const test = [{ col1: "na", col2: "string", col3: "na" }, { col1: 100, col2: "String", col3: "2019-01-01" }, { col1: 203, col2: "na", col3: "2019-01-01" }]

replace(test, 'na', undefined);

console.log(test);
```

Comment: I love this approach, I've been trying to play with the code for a couple days now to expand the function to take on an array for the search - any pointers `replace(object, ["na", null, "-"], undefined)`

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, for array of object return an object from map. Create a separate function which will accept a value.Check if the value is a string and if it is `na`. If so then return `undefined` from the function

```js
const test = [{
    col1: "na",
    col2: "string",
    col3: "na"
  },
  {
    col1: 100,
    col2: "String",
    col3: "2019-01-01"
  },
  {
    col1: 203,
    col2: "na",
    col3: "2019-01-01"
  }
]

let newTest = test.map((item, index) => {
  return {
    col1: replaceNA(item.col1),
    col2: replaceNA(item.col2),
    col3: replaceNA(item.col3)
  }
});

console.log(newTest)

function replaceNA(val) {
  if (typeof val === 'string' && val.toLowerCase() === 'na') {
    return undefined;
  }
  return val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can `map` the array and use `for..in` to check if the value is "na", replace it with `undefined` : ( remove `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` if you want to mutate the original )

```js
const test = [
  { col1: "na", col2: "string", col3: "na" },
  { col1: 100, col2: "String", col3: "2019-01-01" },
  { col1: 203, col2: "na", col3: "2019-01-01" }
];

const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test)).map(o => {
  for (let k in o) {
    if (o[k] === "na") o[k] = undefined;
  }

  return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map the array and use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to replace the items.

```js
const test = [
{col1: "na", col2: "string", col3: "na"},
{col1: 100, col2: "String", col3: "2019-01-01"},
{col1: 203, col2: "na", col3: "2019-01-01"}
]

let r = test.map(itm => {
  return Object.entries(itm).reduce((acc, itm) => {
    acc[itm[0]] = itm[1] == 'na' ? undefined : itm[1]
    return acc
  }, itm)
})

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways, first one where you mutate the original array and and the second one where you don't.

1. You mutate the original array of objects, replace the `"na"` with `undefined` in each iteration of the `forEach()` callback:

```js
const test = [
{col1: "na", col2: "string", col3: "na"},
{col1: 100, col2: "String", col3: "2019-01-01"},
{col1: 203, col2: "na", col3: "2019-01-01"}
];

//mutated original array
function naOmit(arr){
  arr.map((obj) =>  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] === "na" ? obj[key] = undefined : key));
  return test;
}

console.log(naOmit(test));
```

2. Using `Array.prototype.reduce` on the keys of your objects, you loop over the elements and do a copy and change the properties on the copied object where the property has a value of `"na"` to `undefined`:

```js
const test = [
{col1: "na", col2: "string", col3: "na"},
{col1: 100, col2: "String", col3: "2019-01-01"},
{col1: 203, col2: "na", col3: "2019-01-01"}
];
     
function naOmit(arr){
    return arr.map((obj) =>  Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, ele) => {
       acc[ele] = obj[ele];
       acc[ele]  = acc[ele]  === "na" ? undefined : acc[ele] ;
       return acc;
     }, {}));
}
console.log(naOmit(test));
    
//The original array is not mutated    
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cycle every row of `rows`, then every column and replace it with `undefined` if it is 'na'.

```js
function naOmit(x) {
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
      if (x[i][j] == 'na') {
        x[i][j] = undefined;
      }
    }
  }
  return x;
}
let rows = [
  ["na", "string", "na"],
  [100, "String", "2019-01-01"],
  [203, "na", "2019-01-01"]
];
console.log(naOmit(rows));
```

Answer (score 1):

Very sort and power code below.

```
const test = [{ col1: "na", col2: "string", col3: "na" },
              { col1: 100, col2: "String", col3: "2019-01-01" },
              { col1: 203, col2: "na", col3: "2019-01-01" }];

test.map((x) => {
    for(let i=0, len = Object.keys(x).length; i<len; i++) {
        x[Object.keys(x)[i]] = x[Object.keys(x)[i]] === 'na' ? undefined : x[Object.keys(x)[i]];
    }
    return x;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what you wanted, but since you mentioned

> or if this is even the right route

And also because I don't get why you would need to have properties defined with `undefined` instead of being `undefined` for real, I thought maybe this could help:

```js
const test = [{ col1: "na", col2: "string", col3: "na" }, { col1: 100, col2: "String", col3: "2019-01-01" }, { col1: 203, col2: "na", col3: "2019-01-01" }]

for(let j in test){
  for(let i in test[j]){
    if(test[j][i] == "na"){
      delete test[j][i];
    }
  }
}

// example:
console.log(test[0].col1);
console.log(test[0].col2);
console.log(test[0].col3);
```

In this example, I simply delete the keys with value `na`, and in the end if you call any of those properties, it will still return the exact same result as in the other answers method.